# AFNetworking 2: How to cancel a AFHTTPRequestOperationManager request?

Tags: afnetworking-2

I migrated my networking functionality from `AFNetworking` to `AFNetworking v2` and instead of `AFHttpClient` I am using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to support iOS6 as well.

My issue is that while in `AFHttpClient` there was the functionality to cancel a pending request using the

```
- (void)cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:(NSString *)method path:(NSString *)path;
```

method, in the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` there is no such obvious method.

What I've done up to now is subclassing `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and declaring  an iVar

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *_currentRequest;
```

When I make a request the code is something like

```
- (void)GetSomething:(NSInteger)ID success:(void (^)(MyResponse *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
{
    _currentRequest = [self GET:@"api/something" parameters:@{@"ID": [NSNumber numberWithInteger:ID]} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        MyResponse *response = [MyResponse responseFromDictionary:responseObject];
        success(response);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failure(error);

    }];
}
```

and I have a

```
- (void)cancelCurrentRequest;
```

methods which all that does is

```
- (void)cancelCurrentRequest
{
    if(_currentRequest) {
        [_currentRequest cancel]; _currentRequest = nil;
    }
}
```

Now, I don't think this is good practice and when the method is called I get  `(NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)` which is why I need some advice on getting this done correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
[manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

**Swift**

```
manager.operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I 've noticed that but what if you want to cancel a specific GET/POST request?

Comment: If you look into the implementation of cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:path, you'll find how to do it. It just iterate all the operations in operationQueue to find ones that match the method and path and cancel them. The reason they remove them in v2 I guess it that they think it's unnecessary to cancel a specific operation?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. An implementation of cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:path in my AFHTTPRequestOperationManager subclass. Thx mate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to subclass `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` , because when you send request, `AFHTTPRequestOperation` returns from the

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(id)parameters
                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

simply save it somewhere or make static and then perform `cancel` when the request need to be canceled.

Example:

```
- (void)sendRequestToDoSomething
{
   static AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation;
   if(operation) //cancel operation if it is running
       [operation cancel];
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
  //configure manager here....

operation = [manager GET:urlString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   //do something here with the response
   operation = nil;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *error) {
{
   //handle error
   operation = nil;
}
```