# Cancel Post request in Afnetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

Hi I am making post request using AFnetworking 2.0.
My request looks like this.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
            [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"some value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x"];

            [manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                //doing something

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                // error handling.
            }];
```

How can i cancel this request???

Comment: possible duplicate of [AFNetworking 2: How to cancel a AFHTTPRequestOperationManager request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143877/afnetworking-2-how-to-cancel-a-afhttprequestoperationmanager-request)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`POST` method return the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` operation. You can cancel it by calling `cancel`.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *post =[manager POST:nil parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  //doing something
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   // error handling.
}];

//Cancel operation
[post cancel];
```

Comment: For AFNetworking 3.0 users the `[manager POST:....] ` now returns a `NSURLSessionDataTask` object.

Answer (score 3):

Tried `[manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations]` ?

Comment: Hi setgiusGee. i have tried this it's not working. i have created instance of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager which is not a operation type. so i cant add this to nsoperationqueue..

Comment: its not working  "[manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations]"