# Objective-C AFnetworking: stopping a request

Tags: objective-c, api, networking

Evening, I'm working with the Marvel-API, trying to download all the characters.

To download all the characters you have to do multiple requests, in each request you can specified the limit and the offset.

So I've set the limit at the max of 100 and for every request I increase the offset by 100.

Doing that, I do infinite request. Of course.

So I thought that I should stop when the "results" array retrieved from the JSON object is empty.

So the logic should be good, I keep requesting characters 100 by 100 until there are no more to retrieve.

But of course working with networking and async code isn't always so easy. And obviously I got stocked.

I'm sure that the problems is in these lines of code:

```
#pragma mark - Requesting data
-(void)getData {
   NetworkManager *networkManager = [NetworkManager alloc];


    while(self.requestMustEnd == false) {
        NSLog(@"offset: %d", networkManager.offset);

        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        [manager GET:networkManager.getUrlPath parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
            [self parseResponseData:responseObject];
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

        [networkManager increaseOffset];
    }

}


#pragma mark - Parsing Method

-(void)parseResponseData:(NSDictionary *)responseDictionary {
    NSArray *marvelArray = [[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"results"];
    if (marvelArray.count == 0) {
        self.requestMustEnd = true;
    }
    for(NSDictionary* marvel in marvelArray)
    {
        Character *currentMarvelEntity = [[Character alloc] initWithMarvel:marvel];
        //NSLog(@"currentMarvelEntity %@", currentMarvelEntity.name);
        [self.marvelCharacters addObject:currentMarvelEntity];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The key part to stop the request is:

```
if (marvelArray.count == 0) {
        self.requestMustEnd = true;
    }
```

But, still, it never end to request. it is not for the if condition, I'm sure. But probably because, having an async code, the getData func no matter what keep requesting data.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143877/afnetworking-2-how-to-cancel-a-afhttprequestoperationmanager-request) may help. Try:

```
[manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```